# Exceptions from Data Lake immutability rule

Tags: architecture, bigdata, etl, event-sourcing, data-lake

[Data Lake should be immutable](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DataLake.html):

> It is important that all data put in the lake should have a clear
>   provenance in place and time. Every data item should have a clear
>   trace to what system it came from and when the data was produced. The
>   data lake thus contains a historical record. This might come from
>   feeding Domain Events into the lake, a natural fit with Event Sourced
>   systems. But it could also come from systems doing a regular dump of
>   current state into the lake - an approach that's valuable when the
>   source system doesn't have any temporal capabilities but you want a
>   temporal analysis of its data. A consequence of this is that data put
>   into the lake is immutable, an observation once stated cannot be
>   removed (although it may be refuted later), you should also expect
>   ContradictoryObservations.

*Are there any expceptions from rule, where it may be considered a good practice to overwrite data in Data Lake?* I suppose no, but some team mates have different understanding.

I think that data provenance and tracebility is needed in case of cummulative algorithm, to be able to reproduce the final state. What if final state isn't dependent on previous results? Is somebody right if he says that Data Lake immutability (event sourcing) in Data Lake are needed only for cummulative algorithms?

For example, you have a full-load daily-basis ingestion of tables A and B, afterwards calculate table C. *If user is interested only in the latest result of C, are there any reasons to keep history (event sourcing based on date partitioning) of A, B and C?*

Another concern may be an ACID compliance - you may have your file corrupted or partially written. But suppose we're discussing the case when the latest state of A and B can be easily restored from source systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any expceptions from rule, where it may be considered a good practice to overwrite data in Data Lake?

The good practice is not overwrite data in the data lake. In case some event was generated with error or bug. New events that compensates the previous one should be produced. That way, the Datalake records all the events history, including compensatory events and eventual reprocessings.

> I think that data provenance and tracebility is needed in case of cummulative algorithm, to be able to reproduce the final state. What if final state isn't dependent on previous results? Is somebody right if he says that Data Lake immutability (event sourcing) in Data Lake are needed only for cummulative algorithms?

The DataLake is the final destiny for all relevant events. Not all events need to be recorded in the Data Lake. Usually, we distinguish between operational/communication and business events. The business events recorded in the DataLake can be used for reprocessing or in new features that depend on the event's history. Isolated events that do not depend on the event's history can also be produced and added to the history. Consequently, we can deduce that the final state does not violate the principle of immutability. For a set of immutable events contiguous in time, we can always produce a final state. So, the answer is not only for cumulative algorithms.

> For example, you have a full-load daily-basis ingestion of tables A and B, afterwards calculate table C. If user is interested only in the latest result of C, are there any reasons to keep history (event sourcing based on date partitioning) of A, B and C?

The starting event for an event history cannot be reproduced. Only after the first event, we can think about the final state. In this particular case, the A and B tuples and aggregations should not be considered events. But the calculation function input. The calculation function input should be recorded in the data lake as a business event. The event X (calculation input) at the end produces the event Y. In case the event X doesn't be recorded in the event's history, Y it should be considered the starting event.

Comment: thank you for so detailed answer, I've read it multiple times. Unfortunatelly I don't understand it, sorry for this in advance. At section 2 - for me still unclear why non-cummulative algorithms require events history; and how business/operational/communicational events terminology influence an answer. Could you bring an example? Section 3 - sounds for me like a game with terminology: "Data lake should be immutable, but if it's muttable - let call it a starting event".

Comment: Section 2 example. Imaging a purchase that we need to calculate the taxes. We need an event with the tax rate (tax_rate_updated) and an event for the item purchase (item_checkout). The final value (produced event) is not dependent on the DataLake neither uses a cumulative algorithm. The same applies to discount coupons.

Comment: Section 3. The immutability happens at the event level. The Datalake is supposed to only increase. The events once recorded in the Datalake are immutable. Should not change. We can make an analogy with a river stream that ends in a dam. The dam change in size. But the water is still the same (immutable).

Comment: About "business/operational/communicational events terminology influence an answer" it is just to clarify that not all events that occur in a system should be recorded. But only those that are relevant for the business and we going need for reprocessing and have value for the business.

Comment: thanks a lot for clarifications! I think I got your points. In your example (Section 2) the algoriths of calculating taxes is not cummulative, but the results are additive (accross date partitions). That's why keeping historical data makes sense. My case differs, at ETL I'm building a dimensional model at data lake before loading it to data warehouse. That means (besides non-cummulative algorithms) that outputs (dimensions) are not additive, I re-calculating the whole state. *Is history (event sourcing) important in my case?*

Comment: for example, I ingest with Nifi the full state of 10 tables, do some ETL transformations and store the latest state to data lake. System is only interested in the latest state of the dimension, data warehouse doesn't need history. For sake of history, SCD type 2 is used, not event sourcing

Comment: Event sourcing is a potential DataLake capability, but it is not the main objective. The Data lake should be considered as a company asset. New solutions and analytics can use data in the data lake not limited to event sourcing. Event sourcing enables rebuild the application state, make temporal queries (the app stage in a point in time) and events replay (republish events if needed).